# Where to declare libraries when using plyrmr

Tags: r, hadoop, parallel-processing, dplyr

Let's imagine a `dplyr` block of code I wish to parallelize with `plyrmr` on hadoop:

```
library(dplyr)
lol <- mtcars %>% group_by(gear) %>% distinct(cyl)
```

Where should I declare the library of dplyr?

Option 1:

```
library(dplyr)
library(plyrmr)

lol <- input(mtcars) %|% group(gear) %|% gapply(function(x){
distinct(cyl)
return(x)
})
```

Option 2:

```
library(plyrmr)

lol <- input(mtcars) %|% group(gear) %|% gapply(function(x){
library(dplyr)
distinct(cyl)
return(x)
})
```

I would tend to think that since each of the nodes of the cluster is more or less independent the safest option is option 2.

Thanks for your help